# Unix for Datastage

Tags: unix, etl, datastage

I have been working on Datastage for a while now. But Never got any chance to work on UNIX environment. I tried to search over the internet for some good learning resources of UNIX for Datastage, but didn't find any. Are there any good resources which I can go through and start my journey with UNIX.

Comment: i want to learn unix, but since i dint have any exposure, i want to know what will be the best approach to start...

Comment: what have you checked?

Answer (score 0):

1.Start with what can be automated in your project. 
2. Arrive with pseudo code/algorithm for the same.
3. Google your requirement then.

This is the easy way to learn.

Answer (score 0):

The fundamentals of developing a DataStage job won't change as you move from Windows to Unix. Administering the DataStage environment will change.

To learn UNIX/LINUX, you have a long way to go, and it will be tough without access to a Unix/Linux machine. If you do get access to a Unix or Linux machine, then any book that teaches you the basics of getting around in Unix or Linux on the command line would be a good starting point. From there, you can spend years learning the intricacies of a Linux/Unix operating system.